# How to configure/run single autosys job on multiple unix servers simultaneously

Tags: autosys

I am working on shell script which will clean all the older logs and I would like to schedule this job autosys but since I have multiple servers where this job should run hence looking for the information that how to create a single JIL file to run the job on multiple boxes ?

Sample JIL:

```
insert_job: cleanup    job_type: cmd
description: "This job will  cleanup logs from server"
machine: <server_name>
owner: <user_name>
max_run_alarm: 0
alarm_if_fail: y
alarm_if_terminated: y
date_conditions: y
send_notification: n
days_of_week: we,sa
start_times: "00:00"
command: /test/autosys/cleanup.sh 
std_out_file: >> /test/autosys/cleanup_`hostname`_`date+%Y%m%d`.out
std_err_file: >> /test/autosys/cleanup_`hostname`_`date+%Y%m%d`.err
```

In another question I read that we can't give multiple server name in machine tag by comma separated because job will run on either of the server. But I want job to be run to all the servers. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Achieving by a single job seems not in the scope of Autosys.

However, the most efficient way to achieve this would be implementing box job.

**Step01**: Create individual jobs for each host, `Cleanup_on_HostA` and `Cleanup_on_HostB` so on

**Step02**: Group the individual job into a box and schedule the box. This way all the jobs inside the box would start parallelly.

**Sample JIL:**

```
insert_job: Housekeeping_Box
job_type: box
date_conditions: y
days_of_week: we,sa
start_times: "00:00"


insert_job: Cleanup_on_HostA
job_type: cmd
box_name: Housekeeping_Box
description: "This job will  cleanup logs from server"
machine: <hostA>
owner: <user_name>
max_run_alarm: 0
alarm_if_fail: y
alarm_if_terminated: y
command: /test/autosys/cleanup.sh 
std_out_file: >> /test/autosys/cleanup_`hostname`_`date+%Y%m%d`.out
std_err_file: >> /test/autosys/cleanup_`hostname`_`date+%Y%m%d`.err

insert_job: Cleanup_on_HostB
job_type: cmd
box_name: Housekeeping_Box
description: "This job will  cleanup logs from server"
machine: <hostB>
owner: <user_name>
max_run_alarm: 0
alarm_if_fail: y
alarm_if_terminated: y
command: /test/autosys/cleanup.sh 
std_out_file: >> /test/autosys/cleanup_`hostname`_`date+%Y%m%d`.out
std_err_file: >> /test/autosys/cleanup_`hostname`_`date+%Y%m%d`.err
```